# Safe to set on this.state just to keep track?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering if it is safe to set `.state` when I need to keep track.

My component, allows user to click it, every time they do it increments `tieId`. On mouse exit of the component, if the `tieId` is different from when they mouse enetered the component, I want to do a save.

I had to keep track on this.state

Is this code approptiate or will it break the React diff checking as I didn't use `this.setState{tieId: ...}`?

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {tieId: -1, onEnt: -1};
    },
    click: function(e) {
        this.state.tieId++;
        if (this.state.tieId > 2) {
            this.state.tieId= -1;
        }
    },
    mouseEnter: function(e) {
        this.state.onEnt = this.state.tieId
    },
    mouseLeave: function(e) {
        if (this.state.tieId != this.state.onEnt) {
            alert('ok saving');
        } else {
            alert('will not save because tie id is same as when entered \n tieId: ' + this.state.tieId + ' \n onEnt: ' + this.state.onEnt);
        }
    },
  render: function() {
    return <div onClick={this.click} onMouseLeave={this.mouseLeave} onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter} >Hello </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage />, mountNode);
```

Can copy paste this code at the React site Live JSX editor - http://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: If you're trying to avoid a re-render for some reason, you might want to try `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Comment: Oo thanks @TwoStraws thats a great idea! Is there anyway to avoid re-rendering if only a certain key in this.state changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `setState()` to make changes to your component state in React.

[In case you don't believe me, here's Dan Abramov saying the same thing](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/588368766691573760) :)

(There's an exception if you're using ES6 classes: your constructor should set `state` directly.)

Comment: Thanks so much I had a feeling this was the case :)